# correct xpath yet find_element_by_xpath fails python

Tags: python, xml, facebook, selenium, xpath

The xpath for the element I am searching for is correct.

All elements before it have been located and have had action taken upon them via xpath.

However for this one instance location by xpath is failing. Almost if the website was actively denying its existence when I search for it in Selenium.

Has anyone had experience with this? Can I be pointed in a direction to learn more about it, and how to fix it.

website I am automating is facebook.com

My mouse is over the form I'm trying to find and input to in the picture below
[image: No I am not worried about you seeing my facebook]

The relevant code is below:

```
    # from facebook homepage search search for the group
waitForElements(['homepageSearchBarsearchButton'])  #STACK OVERFLOW CODE FAILS HERE
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath((xpath['homepageSearchField']))
element.send_keys(passedText['homepageSearchBarInput'])
time.sleep(randomWait())
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath['homepageSearchBarsearchButton'])
element.click()
```

wait For Elements function below

```
def waitForElements(xpaths = [], *args):
elementLoad = None

for x in xpaths:
 # noinspection PyRedeclaration
 elementLoad =  WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath[x])))
```

The failure trace below:

```
  File "/home/honeytoes/PycharmProjects/Chicags20sEarly30s/lookingForTagCompliance/lookingForTagCompliance/workingFile.py", line 108, in <module>
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath['groupSearchField'])
      File "/home/honeytoes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 258, in find_element_by_xpath
        return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
      File "/home/honeytoes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
        {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
      File "/home/honeytoes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "/home/honeytoes/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='u_jsonp_5_2']/span/span/input"}
    Stacktrace:
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about we make an alternative readable selector based on `placeholder` attribute:

```
//input[@placholder="Search this group"]
```

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure of what you mean. A readable selector is that a term that I'll be able to search for and learn more about? Or can you point me in the direction I should go to get up to speed on the details of your solution? Thank you

Comment: @ChristopherJakob sorry for confusion. What I meant is try using the suggested xpath expression instead of `.//*[@id='u_jsonp_5_2']/span/span/input`.

Comment: Oh I see, so your calling in xpath that searches for the field with the placeholder text "Search this group". Smart, I'll give that a try now

Comment: currently running it, however there is still the issue of the search button press. Perhaps however I can just send the Enter key

Comment: Thank you @alecxe, however the suggested fix did not work, I will continue to dig

Comment: @ChristopherJakob okay, thanks for the update. Are you sure that the input is actually getting visible?

Comment: I used fire path to grab the xpath. It is possible that I am grabbing the xpath of the entire element and not the actual text field, but if such were the case, I would imagine, it would of failed on the ones before it. Down into the rabbit hole I go.